# phantomjs-node page.evaulate seems to hang

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I have an implementation of 'waitfor' with phantomjs-node and it seems that the `sitepage.evaluate` has a big lag compared to when it should evaluate true.   You'll see below that I'm logging out the content value and the content logs with what should evaluate as true, but this doesn't seem to occur for a good 10 seconds or so after the fact.

Any idea what would cause this delay or if there's a better way to evaluate?

```
let Promise = require('bluebird');
let phantom = require('phantom');
let sitepage;
let phInstance;

phantom.create()
    .then(instance => {
        phInstance = instance;
        return instance.createPage();
    })
    .then(page => {
        sitepage = page;
        return page.open('https://thepiratebay.org/search/game/0/99/0');
    })
    .then(status => {

        return waitUntil(function() {

           //This returns the correct content after a short period, while the evaluate ends up taking maybe 10s longer, after this content should evaluate true.
           sitepage.property('content').then(content => {
             console.log(content);
           });

           return sitepage.evaluate(function() {
              return document.getElementById('searchResult');
           });

        }).then(function() {
            return sitepage.property('content');
        }).catch(Promise.TimeoutError, function(e) {
            sitepage.close();
            phInstance.exit();
        });

    })
    .then(content => {
        console.log('content');
        console.log(content);
        sitepage.close();
        phInstance.exit();
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        phInstance.exit();
    });


var waitUntil = (asyncTest) => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        function wait() {
            console.log('--waiting--');
            asyncTest().then(function(value) {
                if (value) {
                    console.log('resolve');
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    setTimeout(wait, 500);
                }
            }).catch(function(e) {
                console.log('Error found. Rejecting.', e);
                reject();
            });
        }
        wait();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, the function sitepage.evaluate returns Element. In my experience, that's a bad idea. You'd better return a short string from sitepage.evaluate. For example, instead of return document.getElementById('searchResult'); you could write:

```
return document.getElementById('searchResult') ? 'true' : '';
```